# Transmission: Watch-dir correctly configured, finds torrent, doesn't add

Tags: linux, debian, bittorrent, transmission

Running transmission-daemon on a debian 7 box and everything works perfectly. Except the watch dir. Transmission picks up any torrent placed in the directory but doesn't add it.

Watch Dir permissions:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 transmission-daemon media  4096 Jun 11 15:22 watch
```

Transmission running: (1001 is user transmission-daemon)

```
1001     21715  0.1  0.0  87560  3132 ?        Ssl  15:16   0:00 /usr/bin/transmission-daemon --config-dir /etc/transmission-daemon --logfile /home/media/transmission.log --log-debug
```

Transmission log:

```
[15:23:00.841] Watching "/home/media/watch/" for new .torrent files (daemon.c:520)
[15:23:00.841] Using inotify to watch directory "/home/media/watch/" (watch.c:73)
[15:23:00.841] Found new .torrent file "wallpapers.torrent" in watchdir "/home/media/watch/" (watch.c:92)
```

And then nada in the web interface.